# Как сделать кнопку "меню" в телеграм боте..? Пишу на Python, наткнулся на такую кнопку в другом боте. Фотографию приложил

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно такую кнопку я хочу сделать, но не имею понятия, как это сделать. Если вы работали с чем-то таким или знаете, где почитать, буду рад.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для более гибкой настройки можно пользоваться возможностями API
Если за основу взят aiogram, то можно в main указать следующего рода код:

```
# Команды для пользователей
    user_commands = [
        BotCommand("start", "Старт"),
    ]
    
# Команды для админов
    admin_commands = [
        BotCommand("start", "Старт"),
        BotCommand("stat", "Статистика"),
    ]
    
async def set_commands(dp: Dispatcher):
    await dp.bot.set_my_commands(user_commands, scope=BotCommandScopeDefault())
    
    for admin in ADMIN_ID:
        await dp.bot.set_my_commands(admin_commands,scope=BotCommandScopeChat(chat_id=admin))
```

Соответственно при запуске бота нужно исполнять set_commands()

Comment: я использую библиотеку pytelegrambotapi..

Comment: @Yan, зачем тогда отмечаете этот ответ как принятый?)

Answer (score 0):

О том, как сделать это меню, рассказывается в [официальной документации Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#menu-button). Воспользуйтесь возможностями @BotFather.